# Receive-Job does not keep my object ordered

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to return an ordered dictionnary for a powershell script ran through a start-job from another script.

The called script return a variable $readahead, which is that type:

```
[DBG]: [Job23]: PS C:\Users\litroma\Documents>> $readahead.GetType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     OrderedDictionary                        System.Object
```

But once this variable is retreive from the caller script, though:

```
$ret=receive-job -Job $job
```

The $ret variable is that type:

```
[DBG]: PS C:\Users\litroma\Documents>> $ret.GetType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     -------- 
True     True     Hashtable                                System.Object
```

Do you know a way to keep my [ordered] type through a receive-job ?

TIA

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that in order to pass pick up the results from the external process that executes the job, it needs to serialize the runtime objects.

Unfortunately, the serialization process seems to turn any `Dictionary` type into a `Hashtable`.

You can see this effect by exporting and re-importing an `ordered` dictionary object:

```
PS C:\> [ordered]@{1=1;2=2;3=3} |Export-Clixml ($tmpFile = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName())
PS C:\> (Import-Clixml $tmpFile).GetType().FullName
System.Collections.Hashtable
```

I don't think this can be overcome without some serious extending of the `OrderedDictionary` class, making the code less reusable.

An alternative is to return an array of objects (arrays are ordered) and then recreating the `OrderedDictionary` after receiving the job

Comment: IMHO, *generic* is not good term here, since `Hashtable` is not generic class in .NET terms.

Comment: @PetSerAl true, removed it to avoid confusion

Comment: Thanks Mathias for the tips.